# WordPress FSE - Problems with passing CSS variable to Site Editor

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages, wordpress-gutenberg

I'm attempting to define a **`--wrotter--background-image`** CSS variable within each of the .html templates of my WordPress theme. Is it possible to have this reflected in the Site Editor? I would appreciate the ability to toggle the presence of the CSS variable within each template, as it is not required universally.

I get the following error in my console:

```
blocks.js?ver=1e16b1d8cd192ec1a469:11756 Block validation: Block validation failed for `core/group` ({name: 'core/group', icon: {…}, keywords: Array(4), attributes: {…}, providesContext: {…}, …}).

Content generated by `save` function:

<main class="wp-block-group" style="margin-top:0"></main>

Content retrieved from post body:

<main class="wp-block-group" style="margin-top:0; --wrotter--background-image: url('../../..//assets/img/background-logo.svg')">
    
</main>
```

Here is my page.html:

```
<!-- wp:template-part {"slug":"header","area":"header","tagName":"header"} /-->

<!-- wp:group {"tagName":"main", "style":{"spacing":{"margin":{"top":"0"}}}} -->
<main class="wp-block-group" style="margin-top:0; --wrotter--background-image: url('../../../assets/img/background-logo.svg')">

</main>
<!-- /wp:group -->

<!-- wp:template-part {"slug":"footer","area":"footer","tagName":"footer"} /-->
```